# creating a pending intent to start a non system app

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I've read plenty of doc, but I still can't figure it out.

Are we allowed to start a 3rd party app(NON SYSTEM APP like as alarm, notification. etc) with a pending intent?

i.e.:

App1

- create pending intent
- start a non system app and send pending intent

App2

- execute its own code
- call pending intent to start App1

I haven't found 1 single example doing this. And according to the doc. you can pass a pending intent to a 3rd party app. It does not specify a system app

does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may launch anything you want with a `PendingIntent`. As long as the component you want to start is exported (publicly available).